# Bad hash function in Cobol

Tags: security, hash, cobol

I work on my code analyser and try write some patterns for Cobol vulnerabilities. I spent too much time for searching some functions in Cobol which use in cryptography.

Maybe anybody now about hashing in Cobol? I don't know this language, but learning this question at this moment.

Comment: When asking about "COBOL" I highly suggest to add information about the OS/compiler in use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM has [a program](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.csfb400/owh.htm) that you can call from a COBOL program and it will return the hashed values. It can handle the following hashes:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- RIPEMD-160
- SHA-224
- SHA-256
- SHA-384
- SHA-512

This will only work on IBM COBOL. The link I provided shows an example of the call and describes all of the data required by the linkage section of CSNBOWH (CSNEOWH if you are using AMODE(64))

Comment: The specification looks a little bit weird, is it really `CALL CSNBOWH( parameter-1, ..., paramer-n)`?

Comment: I followed the link and typed up an example program.  It seems to work, sharing it here for the world to see.

(sigh, I can't do that as the question is mark closed. :( )
(too long and can't paste in comment, going to do an "answer" below.)

Comment: @KaLam I have rolled back your answer as I cannot test it. You will need to wait for the question to be re-opened. if you want to answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard function in COBOL. Therefore you have two options:

1st - on any PC-based COBOL implementation you should be able to just call the libcrpyto functions or other C libraries. A sample is [md5er.cob](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/c_libraries/md5er.cob).

2nd - use a plain COBOL implementation for example [COBDES](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/cobdes/cobdes.cob) or the [cobsha programs, providing SHA-3 implementation](https://sourceforge.net/p/open-cobol/contrib/HEAD/tree/trunk/samples/cobsha3/) (or write your own).

Comment: Thank you, Simon!

Comment: @IvanKrasnov You're welcome - please either edit your question and comment on answers what is missing for you or "accept" the answer that "worked for *you*" [a privilege you have] and upvote all answers you consider useful [if you have the privilege to do so, if not, come back later when you have] (I highly suggest to work through the StackOverflow tutorial).